# What is actually there in Bhrigu Samhita?

Tags: scripture, horoscopes

I have heard that there is a book called `Bhrigu Samhita` somewhere in Hoshiyarpur, India, which can tell about any person's past, present and future births based on his/her janam kundli (astrological chart prepared at the time of birth). Is it true?

I want to know what all is written in that book and how can one tell about a future/past life by looking at the present janam's kundli. Also, is there some other text/stories written in it.

Please provide  any online/downloadable version of the same book present with Hindi/English translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched on google and found a [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhrigu_Samhita) for the same so thought of posting it here for the other people who are also in search of the answer. Another reason for posting here is that since wikipedia is open to people for changing the text, so there were chances that the information might be lost or modified.

The Bhrigu Saṃhitā is an astrological (Jyotish) classic attributed to Maharishi Bhrigu during the Vedic period, Treta yuga. It is said that it was compiled by the Sage out of compassion for humanity so that humanity could cope with the pressures of its existence and move towards a more spiritual nature.[1] The Bhrigu Samhita is said to contain predictions on the current and future lives as well as information on the past life. These predictions will be accurate based on the actions (karma) of the questioner.

### Origin

The Ashram of Maharishi was in present day Ballia (U.P.), India. Major part of Bhṛgu Saṃhitā was destroyed during Muslim Invasions of that time.

Maharishi Bhrigu was the first compiler of predictive astrology. He compiled about 500,000 horoscopes and recorded the life details and events of various persons. This formed a database for further research and study. This study culminated in the birth of the science (Śāstra) of determining the quality of time (Horā) and is the Bṛhat Parāśara Horā Śāstra.

These Horoscopes were based upon the planetary positions of the Sun, Moon, Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Rāhu (North Node of the Moon) and Ketu (South Node of the Moon).

After that, Maharishi Bhṛigu gave his predictions on different types of horoscopes compiled by him with the help of Lord Gaṇeśa in a brief and concise manner. The total permutations/possible horoscope charts that can be drawn with this is about 45 million. Maharishi taught this art of predictions to his son (Śukra) and other pupils.

### Lost manuscript

Currently the original Bhṛigu saṃhitā as a book is not available. During foreign invasions of India by Muslims from the northwest in the 12<sup>th</sup> and 13th<sup>th</sup> centuries, the brahmin community became dispersed all over India. The invaders captured these prime assets of the brahmins. Some parts of the 'Bhṛgu Saṃhitā' were taken away by them. The most unfortunate and destructive event was the destruction of the Nalanda university library by then Muslim rulers, where several thousands of the horoscopes compiled by Maharṣi Bhṛgu had been stored. Only a small percentage of the original horoscopes of Bhṛgu Saṃhitā remained with the Brahmin community which are now scattered throughout various parts of India. Many of the pages scattered in North of India were with Pt. Deshraj Sharma from Hoshiarpur, Punjab (North India) who also had this as an undertaking from government of India. The city of Hoshiarpur was famous for Bhrigu Shastris.