# If all my sufferings are due to my previous life's karma I did, then what is the evidence that in my previous life I did bad karma?

Tags: karma, rebirth, life

Hindu puranas and scriptures says all sufferings and happiness are due to the karma we did in our previous life.
If so, then what is the evidence about my previous life' s karma. How can I blindly believe in law of Karma.
Also how can I know about my previous life ?

Comment: "Also how can I know about my previous life "is answered here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8446/how-can-one-know-about-their-previous-births/9588#9588 - So you will need a litle editing of  the quesion .

Comment: The evidence is Hindu scripture